# Java Spring MVC Webform POST Request Method

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, post, request

I want that the method showEnteredData is executed if the Button is pressed.
But it does not execute the function. I thought it should do automaticly.
What is the problem? 
Thanks for your help :=)

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>

    <div id="leer" style="float: left;"></div>
    <div class="filmFilter">
        <form action="articles" method="get">

            <select name="dropdownFilmeFilter">
                <option value="aufsteigend">Preis: aufsteigend</option>
                <option value="absteigend">Preis: absteigend</option>
                <option value="bewertung">Kundenbewertung</option>
                <option value="erscheinungsdatum">Erscheinungsdatum</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Done" /> <a href="home">bring me back
                home</a>
        </form>

    </div>

@RequestMapping(value = "/articles")
public String showHome ( Model model){
    List<Article> article = (List<Article>) gd.findAll(Article.class);  
    model.addAttribute("articles", article);


    return "articles";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/articles", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showEnteredData(@RequestParam("dropdownFilmeFilter") String filter, Model model) {
    System.err.println("hohooh");


    List<Article> article = (List<Article>) gd.sortByAttribute(Article.class, "price", true);
    article.clear();

    if (filter == "aufsteigend"){
        article = (List<Article>) gd.sortByAttribute(Article.class, "price", true);
    }
    model.addAttribute("articles", article);

    return "articles";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either change the method in your form tag to "post", or change your @RequestMapping's method to RequestMethod.GET. I would recommend the first option.

Comment: +1 for changing the form to POST - semantically, there's no good reason to use GET for a form, and that has potential to confuse future maintainers (who may or may not be you).